# Unable to log to google stackdriver logging django + gunicorn + nGINX?

Tags: django, logging, gunicorn, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've tried the below code for logging in django settings

```
from google.cloud import logging as google_cloud_logging

log_client = google_cloud_logging.Client()
log_client.setup_logging()

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'stackdriver_logging': {
            'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
            'client': log_client
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['stackdriver_logging'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': [
                'stackdriver_logging',
                'mail_admins'
            ],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        }
    },
}
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
workers = 3
loglevel = "debug"
proc_name = "hhh"
daemon = False
```

I was able write to stackdriver logging with django development server but  logging not working when I use gunicorn. But `django.request` is working.

**Problem: logger "django" not being called and showing no errors with gunicorn**

Please help.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  Provide specifics about the actual error.

Comment: @RobertHarvey updated the question. please check.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `LOGGING`?

Comment: Tried it also but it didn't work...

Comment: What about https://medium.com/google-cloud/setting-up-stackdriver-logging-for-django-on-gcp-a0190c1b0a79 ?

Comment: I tried it it's working with dev server but not working with gunicorn

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After trying many ways finally it worked with below configuration

> gcp_utils/stackdriver_logging.py

```
import logging
import traceback
from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter
from google.cloud import error_reporting, logging as google_cloud_logging


client = error_reporting.Client()
log_client = google_cloud_logging.Client()
log_client.setup_logging()


class StackdriverErrorHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            request = record.request
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                user = request.user.email
            else:
                user = 'Anonymous'
            status_code = getattr(record, 'status_code', None)
            http_context = error_reporting.HTTPContext(
                method=request.method,
                url=request.build_absolute_uri(),
                user_agent=request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT'),
                referrer=request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'),
                response_status_code=status_code,
                remote_ip=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            http_context = None

        if record.exc_info:
            exc_info = record.exc_info
        else:
            exc_info = (None, record.getMessage(), None)
        reporter = ExceptionReporter(request, is_email=True, *exc_info)
        tb_frames = reporter.get_traceback_frames()
        if tb_frames:
            tb = tb_frames[-1]
        else:
            tb = {}
        report_location = {
            'filePath': tb.get('filename'),
            'lineNumber': tb.get('lineno'),
            'functionName': tb.get('function')
        }
        client._send_error_report(
            message=traceback.format_exc(),
            http_context=http_context,
            user=user,
            report_location=report_location
        )
```

> settings.py

```
import sys
from google.cloud import logging as google_cloud_logging


log_client = google_cloud_logging.Client()

if not DEBUG:
  LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'stackdriver_logging': {
            'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
            'client': log_client
        },
        'stackdriver_error_reporting': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'gcp_utils.stackdriver_logging.StackdriverErrorHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'stackdriver_logging'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': [
                'stackdriver_logging',
                'mail_admins'
            ],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        }
    },
}
```

> gunicorn.conf.py

```
from google.cloud import logging as google_cloud_logging

log_client = google_cloud_logging.Client()
log_client.setup_logging()

bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
workers = 3
loglevel = "debug"
proc_name = "django_app"
daemon = False
pythonpath = "/path/to/python/"
timeout = 90
accesslog = '/home/user/logs/debug.log'
logconfig_dict = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'stackdriver_logging': {
            'class': 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler',
            'client': log_client
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'gunicorn.access': {
            'handlers': ['stackdriver_logging'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': [
                'stackdriver_logging',
                'mail_admins'
            ],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        }
    },
}
```

running gunicorn process

```
$ gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py wsgi:application
```

We must define the `logconfig_dict` in-order to make it work with google stackdriver logging.

Comment: what module is `gcp_utils.stackdriver_logging.StackdriverErrorHandler` coming from ?

Comment: Is that code you could share maybe ? I have still not been able to get tracebacks into google-cloud but still log them to sentry instead, while logs are in stackdriver ...